# Java generics type reference

Tags: java, generics

I just stumbled with a situation I think I have not tried before.
I have this:

```
class A<DATA>

class B extends A<SomeSpecificDataClass>
```

Now, I want to declare a third class like this:

```
class C <T extends A<DATA>{
    public someMethod(T instance, DATA data){}
}
```

I know I could just ask the instance for its data, but for the API I'm building, I'd REALLY prefer to have a syntax like this. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `DATA` would be another generic? Well, you can only declare `class C<DATA, T extends A<DATA>>`.

Comment: Review this [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: @Luiggi What you say actually solves my problem! Thank you. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DATA` would be another generic, then you should declare that the class uses two generics:

```
class C<DATA, T> {
}
```

Then, you could define other requirements for `T` based on `DATA`:

```
class C<DATA, T extends A<DATA>> {
}
```